# Select by attribute with field equal to element of vector in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, arcgis-10.6, error-000358

I am trying to select by an attribute with a condition that field equals to an element of a vector. I use a for loop but could not get the right expression for this condition. Here are my codes.

```
random37 = [30449, 46617, 17309]
pointlayer = "network_nodeSelected"

for random in random37:

randomname = "n" + str(random)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(pointlayer,pointlayer)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(pointlayer,'NEW_SELECTION','"ARC_" = random')
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pointlayer, randomname)

print randomname
```

The error message is presented as follows.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 6, in 
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(pointlayer,'NEW_SELECTION','"ARC_" = point')

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 7742, in SelectLayerByAttribute
    raise e

ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

As you can see, my problem is the expression '"ARC_" = random'. But I do not know how to get the right expression.

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented?  I suspect the error message will lead you to an answer in an existing Q&A here. Also, your three functions can be replaced by Select_analysis() for simpler code.

Comment: @PolyGeo, thanks for helping. I have added the error message. The error is the invalid expression and failed to execute SelectLayerByAttribute. Could you help me find the right expression? Really appreciate!

Comment: Click the tag button for ERROR 000358 to see how others have researched/solved this.

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks for your suggestions. I find a similar question and post my solution.

Comment: Which question did you find?  This Q&A should almost certainly be a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the sql expression. Here is the solution.

```
random37 = [30449,46617,17309]
pointlayer = "network_nodeSelected"
layer1 = "wqi_ConProshp"

for point in random37:
    pointname = "n" + str(point)
    fieldname = 'ARC_'
    whereClause = """{0} = {1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(pointlayer, fieldname),point)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(pointlayer,pointlayer)    
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(pointlayer,'NEW_SELECTION',whereClause)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pointlayer, pointname)
    #select the location and then export it

    print pointname
```

To be honest, I still can not understand how it works but it indeed solves my problem.

Comment: In your original post, the where clause literally had the word "random" in the string as opposed to the value of the variable called `random`.  In this example, the string `format()` method is inserting the actual value into the string